# Blackberry: How can I make a buttonfield act like toggle button?

Tags: blackberry, toggle, buttonfield

I have a single button which I want to use as Start/Stop button. How can I make the buttonfield work as toggle button?

Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just change button label on fieldChange or navigationClick or touchEvent, don't forget to save toggle state in class member:

```
class ToggleButtonField extends ButtonField {
    int mToggleState = -1;
    String[] mLabels = {};
    public ToggleButtonField(String[] labels) {
        super(CONSUME_CLICK);
        if(labels != null && labels.length > 0)
        {
            mLabels = labels;
            mToggleState = 0;
            updateLabel();                  
        }       
    }

    private void updateLabel() {
        setLabel(mLabels[mToggleState]);        
    }

    protected void fieldChangeNotify(int context) {
        mToggleState = getNextToggleState(mToggleState);
        updateLabel();
        super.fieldChangeNotify(context);
    }

    private int getNextToggleState(int state) {
        int result = mToggleState+1;
        if(result >= mLabels.length)
            result = 0;
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi there i tried using this class like - String[] labels={"Yes","No"};  
           edord = new ToggleButtonField(labels); edord.setChangeListener(this);  grid2.add(edord);//But i dont see anything on screen what else do i need to do

Comment: @Jatin does grid2 stands for GridFieldManager? Have you added grid2 to screen manager? If still not work, can you post new question in satckoverflow and put link here in comment? Thank you.